# SQL Azure - How can I select sysdatabases table from master database in SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure

In SQL Azure, I try this:

> select * From master.dbo.sysdatabases

And get this error:

> Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.dbo.sysdatabases' is not supported in this version of SQL Server

What should I do to be able to run that query in SQL Azure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use the system *view* [sys.databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff951625.aspx) (without the master qualification, it is not needed)

The system *table* [sysdatabases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179900.aspx) has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005 (Azure is a later version) and in any case is [not supported on Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336269.aspx)

Comment: Some of the information provided is incorrect. Running select * From master.dbo.sysdatabases within master directly returns the list of databases. So it is supported. The link provided to the unsupported statements does not include sysdatabases.

Comment: @HerveRoggero: I don't Azure to test against. I read it as not supported. It's still deprecated and should not be used though.

Comment: @GBN: You are right. The same with dbo.sysindexes. We can replace sysindexes by sys.indexes in SQl Azure.

Comment: @gbn your link to "not supported on Azure" is not available. Please change it.

Comment: Love how the Azure team simple removed all older documentation.

Comment: @gbn - but for some reason, logged in as the *same user*, but USE-ing in a diff DB, sys.database gives different results than what master.sys.database would. Why is that? It's not showing DB's *that the user owns* when USE-ing a diff DB.

Comment: @mmcrae no idea. I guess it's because of permissions and whether you've GRANT or DENY on VIEW ANY DATABASE and stuff., Also db_owner is not the same as owner_sid in sys.databases

Comment: @gbn - seems like a quirk with Azure SQL DB (PaaS) where the sys.databases inside `master` DB gives diff results than the sys.database inside a custom DB.

Comment: @gbn take a look here.  It is by design that master sys.databases shows master and all databases on the server.  User databases only show master and the current database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because you are running this statement from another database than master. You cannot add "master." to your statements unless you are already on the master database. More generally speaking, you cannot issue statements that execute a command on another database than the one you are on.

You can run the statement without the database qualification, and it will run, as gbn is suggesting. Or you can connect to master and execute it as-is.